# Crear una interface dentro de otra interface Angular 2

Tags: angular, interface

Estoy intentando crear una interface dentro de otra interface, pero al momento de usarla me dice que las propiedades de la interface interna no pertenecen a la externa

```
interface Respuesta {
    pregunta:number,
    valor:number
}

export interface Valoracion {
    materia:number,
    respuestas:Respuesta[]
}
```

Si al iniciar el componente intento realizar esta asignación

```
public valoracion:Valoracion[] = [{
   materia:1,
   respuestas: [
      {valor:3, pregunta:1},
      {valor:4, pregunta:2}
    ]
}];
```

y me aparece el error que respuestas no pertenece a Valoración, si quito respuestas de la interface como de la valoración funciona sin problemas

Gracias por su respuestas

Comment: Cual es el fin de usar interfaces?, en su lugar podrías usar clases

Comment: @LordOfLies son cosas totalmente distintas, cada una tiene su utilidad. Por otro lado, cada atributo debería tener un `;` al final, no una coma

Answer (score -1):

Tal vez sea un bug en la versión de TypeScript que estes utilizando o en el IntellSense porque sintacticamente no tiene ningún problema. En concreto recree tu ejemplo en [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxfejg) y funciona correctamente.